# Inside a circle of radius $r$ insert a triangle with the largest possible area.

Tags: calculus, geometry, lagrange-multiplier, extremal-graph-theory

I thought I could use this $r$, being the circumradius of the triangle, thereby the area being: $\frac{abc}{4r}$. Now from here I need to find a,b,c so the area is maximal. Could I do this with Lagrange coefficients adding a requirement? I dont know which though.. This question was asked when doing conditional extremes..

Comment: Are you asking only about the method of Lagrange coefficients, or would you also want a simpler method?

Comment: Method of Lagrange coefficients and the other one for sport if possible. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We define function $f$ which calculates triangle area by its angles like this: $(A\,,B\,,C \lt\pi)$
$$f(A,B,C)=2R^2\cdot\sin A\cdot\sin B\cdot \sin C$$
And function $g$ like this:
$$g(A,B,C)=A+B+C=\pi$$
Now we need to solve:
$$\cos A\cdot2R^2\sin B\cdot\sin C=\lambda\qquad (1)\\[2ex]
\cos B\cdot2R^2\sin C\cdot\sin A=\lambda\qquad (2)\\[2ex]
\cos C\cdot2R^2\sin A\cdot\sin B=\lambda\qquad (3)\\[2ex]
A+B+C=\pi\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad (4)$$
Setting $(1)\,,(2)\,,(3)$ equal will show us:
$$\cos A\cdot\sin B=\cos B\cdot\sin A\Rightarrow \sin(A-B)=0\\[2ex]
\cos B\cdot\sin C =\cos C\cdot\sin B\Rightarrow \sin(B-C)=0\\[2ex]
\cos C\cdot\sin A=\cos A\cdot\sin C\Rightarrow \sin(C-A)=0\\[2ex]$$
And since $A\,,B\,,C$ are angles of a triangle we can conclude:
$$A=B=C=\frac{\pi}{3}\qquad,\lambda=\frac{3R^2}{4}$$
Therefore the triangle with maximal area is the equilateral triangle.